# How to make Sodium dichromate

Tags: synthesis

I've been trying to make Sodium dichromate $\ce{Na2Cr2O7}$ by following these steps:

- Dissolve an inox spoon in $\ce{H2SO4}$
- Filter the solution
- Dissolve the obtained sludge in $\ce{NaClO}$
- Heat the solution until slurries appear
- Filter the solution

The solution I obtained was yellowish (light yellow), I tried to add some acid to see the orange color of the (hypothetical) dichromate but nothing happened!

I added some ammonia before acidifying the solution, nothing as well.

1st: Is this method the right one to obtain chromate/dichromate?
2nd: If yes, why didn't the orange color appear?

Comment: While inox spoon's may indeed contain chromium, this [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stainless_steel) states "at least 10.5 mass%" and "up to 26% is used for harsh environments".  So, it is still a small fraction of your spoon that constitutes chromium.  So it is *more* likely your first solution became yellow in color because of an other major constituent, iron. Yet I doubt a moderate oxidant like bleach is able to oxidize metallic chromium to yield a significant amount of chromates, $\ce{CrO4^{2-}}$ and dichromates $\ce{Cr2O7^{2-}}$, the later a known *strong* oxidizer.

Comment: bleach is able to oxidate chromium to chromate in *strongly basic conditions*, i.e. under excess of bleach in concentrated sodium hidroxide. However, the method itself is questionable, as inox contains too small amount of chromium.

Comment: Back in the days when cancer wasn't invented yet, people used to clean glassware with hot solutions of $\ce{CrO3}$ or $\ce{Na2Cr2O7}$ in sulfuric acid. If you work with (di)chromates, protect yourself and the environment. Please wear gloves and don't dump the solutions in the sink.

Comment: Does one of these steps isolate iron from chrome? If not is there any method to do it? Remark that I'm not chemist but have some basic notions of chemistry.
I wore gloves throughout the handling, how do I get rid of these materials then?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the [chromate ion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_chromate) $\ce{CrO4^{2-}}$ has chromium in the +6 oxidation state like dichromate $\ce{Cr2O7^{2-}}$. Chromate is yellow, dichromate is orange.

From the Wikipedia article on [sodium chromate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_chromate): sodium chromate is formed by reaction of dichromate with hydroxide:

$$\ce{Na2Cr2O7 + 2NaOH -> 2Na2CrO4 + H2O}$$

You may be making sodium dichromate, but the strongly basic conditions are converting it to sodium chromate.

Comment: When I add acid in excess, it normally (re-)convert to $\ce{Cr2O72-}$?